# google calendar The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid

Tags: google-calendar-api

please when go to activate 
 Enabled the Google Calendar API ,i have this pupop notify

Couldn't create brand
warning
The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid

please

Comment: Please specify more in detail how you got this error. How did you try to enable the Calendar API?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same error and I used the developer console to inspect the response.

I see `{"0":{"type":"client_auth_config","subject":"?error_code=9&error_field_name=CreateClientRequest.client.type&error_field_value=TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"}}` for my case.

So I click `Create Credentials` -> `OAuth Client ID`, and this seems resolve the issue.