# Add *.googleusercontent.com to Authorized JavaScript origins

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, add-on, http-status-code-400

We have an add-on for Google Sheets and would like to switch other Google accounts for some functions.

Half a year ago, I successfully added a URL (https://***.googleusercontent.com) to **Authorized JavaScript origins** and a URL ([https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/\*\*\](https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/%5C*%5C*%5C)*) to **Authorized redirect URIs**.

But now we can't and, therefore, it keeps showing

> **Authorization Error** (Error:400: redirect_uri_mismatch).

When I try to add this URL(https://***.googleusercontent.com), it shows

> "Save failed! The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid."

I don't know whether the rules changed and what should I do. See the screenshot for details. Thanks!

> **Error Message**: The JavaScript origin in the request, https://***.googleusercontent.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

[image: The JavaScript origin in the request, https://***.googleusercontent.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.]

[image: Trying to add a new URI]

Comment: ``When I try to add this URL(https://***.googleusercontent.com), it shows

    "Save failed! The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid."`` To be clear, `***` in `https://***.googleusercontent.com` is  actual ascii characters. right?

Comment: Yes, like this: `https://n-kcfn2rzfaub2x2qhuzyqgl5wawaisnsrtij6ooi-2lu-script.googleusercontent.com`

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236466 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862586

Comment: Is this the same URL as was previously (and successfully) added? Or are you trying to add a second JS origin?

Comment: We have a new add-on, so the URL is different. But I also tried adding the same URL to the **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** for the new add-on and adding a second URL for the old add-on. Both of them are failed.

Comment: Try creating a issue in the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)

Comment: After commenting, there was already a issue filed and rejected. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64348169 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170768105 EDIT: I'm guessing this is yours: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170740549

Answer (score 4):

#### This appears to be a bug.

The issue you reported on Issue Tracker has been forwarded internally:

- [Fail to Add *.googleusercontent.com into Authorized JavaScript origins](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170740549)

> Thank you for bringing this to our attention. It has been forwarded internally.

Posting this here to give it more visibility. Please click the top-left star if you're affected by this.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, since October I am not allowed to use *.googleusercontent.com as Authorized origin.

I reported it on Issue Tracker, but their answer simply was "Thank you for your report, unfortunately Issuetracker is not the proper forum to address your report".

I solved this problem (At least temporarily) by inserting the Google sign-in button on an external site (Github pages) and once logged, redirect the user to my *.googleusercontent.com page with the sign-in token inserted in the URL as a parameter.