# Use oAuth 2.0 in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

Description:
Since October, when creating an OAuth 2.0 client credential, in authorized JavaScript sources, I cannot register URIs from `googleusercontent.com` domain, used in Google Apps Script web app.

Example / Steps to reproduce the problem

1. Open the OAuth 2.0 credentials console
2. Add the next google web app JavaScript origin `https://n-rzzilggwjj2adcfyrz2h2nyog7wljc2s2ern2vq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com` or simply `https://googleusercontent.com`
3. I get the next message error:

> The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.

How can I create a Google OAuth 2.0 client credential to use Google sign in in my web app?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321902/add-googleusercontent-com-to-authorized-javascript-origins

Comment: Try creating a issue in the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)

Comment: It seems you already [created a issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170768105). Add it to your question for wider audience by [edit]ing your question.