# How to add appengine preview urls to Google OAuth Authorized domains

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to add appengine preview urls to authorized domain without specifying each preview url? Wildcards no longer work and I find it a chore to add every preview url dynamically generated for the app. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What portion of the url you want to set as wirldcard? The project id, version ...?

Comment: It doesn't allow wildcard. I updated the question with an image that shows this.

Comment: As per this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170740549#comment34) comment,the use of wildcard as OAuth origins or redirect URIs is blocked in order to ensure the security and privacy of user accounts. you can try the workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490062/18265570)